# Find the next term in the number series?

Tags: number-sequence

> $9, 27, 31, 155, 161, 1127, ?$

I observed that the first term and second term respectively are $3^2$ and $3^3$. But I have no idea about the subsequent terms. 
One more observation I did was, the difference in all of these: 
$$9, +18= 27,+4=31,+124=155,+6=161,+966=1127.$$
We see the after each alternate number, the difference is increasing: $4,6,...$ so next should be $8$, which gives the answer as $1135$. Which is surprisingly correct. But what is the pattern in the middle numbers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to be x3, +4, x5, +6, x7, +8 and so on

Comment: Oh great observation! I will accept it in a short while.